# Wrong state class, expecting View State but received class android.widget.CompoundButton$SavedState instead

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-view

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Wrong state class`, expecting View State but received `class android.widget.CompoundButton$SavedState` instead. This usually happens when two views of different type have the same id in the same hierarchy. This view's **id is id/0x2**. Make sure other views do not use the same id.

its occurs when screen rotate and when when trying go back to the fragment no id is repeated plzz some one help me

Comment: no id duplication i saw

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more... showing some code, the hierarchy of your activity / fragment, ... there is not enough information.

Comment: Related - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1325576/wrong-state-class-expecting-view-state-exception-in-android-1-5-with-custom-v

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i have resolve it .... its because of duplication of ids of view mostly when we  add view dynamically and not set ids (with same text of radio button in my case)

to resolve first check all views those u are adding dynamically

Comment: i didnt undertand can u elaborate more?

Comment: Is there a tool or something to detect these kinds of issues?

Answer (score 8):

As the question described why this happens.

> This usually happens when two views of different type have the same id
>   in the same hierarchy.

Exactly, there will two different types of views having the same ids, which might happen on inflating views dynamically.
In my case, I have a two `ViewStub` with same view `id` and `inflatedId`, thus, after inflation of a view. Application went to a state that one ViewStub and other inflated view was present in the view hierarchy with the same id which result in the crash.

Comment: In my case, included ViewGroup and it's child had the same id, resulting the crash

Answer (score 6):

In my case I implemented  `onRestoreInstanceState` not correctly trying to send my custom `SavedState` class to `super.onRestoreInstanceState`

I solved it sending `savedState.getSuperState` to the super call.

Answer (score 4):

I was just dealing with this issue when working with customViews and parcelable, trying to persist the state of my view with `onSaveInstanceState()` and `onRestoreInstanceState()`, and I was getting this same error. However I found a work around when I changed the Implementation of these above functions. I will share the before and after.

This was my before. The difference is slight.

```
 override fun onSaveInstanceState(): Parcelable {
    val bundle = Bundle()
    bundle.putParcelable("superState", super.onSaveInstanceState())
    bundle.putParcelableArrayList("boxState", ArrayList(boxen))

    super.onSaveInstanceState()
    return bundle
}

override fun onRestoreInstanceState(state: Parcelable) {
    var viewState = state
    if (viewState is Bundle) {
        boxen = viewState.getParcelableArrayList("boxState")!!
        viewState = viewState.getParcelable("superState")!!
    }
    val test = boxen
    Log.i(TAG, "Bundle received: $boxen and $test and finally $viewState")

    super.onRestoreInstanceState(state)
}
```

And this is my after.

```
override fun onSaveInstanceState(): Parcelable {
    val bundle = Bundle()
    bundle.putParcelable("superState", super.onSaveInstanceState())
    bundle.putParcelableArrayList("boxState", ArrayList(boxen))

    super.onSaveInstanceState()
    return bundle
}

override fun onRestoreInstanceState(state: Parcelable) {
    var viewState = state
    if (viewState is Bundle) {
        boxen = viewState.getParcelableArrayList("boxState")!!
        viewState = viewState.getParcelable("superState")!!
    }
    val test = boxen
    Log.i(TAG, "Bundle received: $boxen and $test and finally $viewState")

    super.onRestoreInstanceState(viewState)
}
```

Somehow all I had to do was return `viewState` to the superClass instead of `state`. I think its because the "state of the view" had not been recovered yet so to speak. We were passing `state` parameter and at that moment, according to the error we received, it was only a raw bundle. We had not yet extracted and assigned the actual `view state`(which happens in the if block) we stashed in the first function, that is why the error says "Wrong state class" and that was  also why using `viewState` worked. I hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

Suppose that you have a ScrollView in a Fragment or DialogFragment, with id:

```js
android:id="@+id/scrollView"
```

You display this Fragment, then change screen orientation, and get this crash:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo { com.company.MyApp/com.company.MyActivity }: 
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Wrong state class, expecting View State 
    but received class android.widget.ScrollView$SavedState instead. 
    This usually happens when two views of different type have the same id 
    in the same hierarchy. This view's id is id/scrollView. Make sure other 
    views do not use the same id.
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
  ...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Wrong state class...
  at android.view.View.onRestoreInstanceState(View.java:13764)
  at android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView.onRestoreInstanceState(NestedScrollView.java:1879)
  ...
```

The fix is to rename the `id` that you're using, like this:

```js
android:id="@+id/scroll_view"
```

I assume that some `id` names are already used by other views in the Android framework, so they are **detected as duplicate names when the view state is restored**. So you have to alter the name of your `id`.

Answer (score 1):

Something similar happened to me, in my case I had one layout for portrait mode and one for the landscape mode. Both had their similarities, but there was two buttons that had same Ids on both layouts, but the type of those two buttons was different in landscape layout. So when I change the orientation of the device to landscape similar error occurred. Fix was to have same type of buttons in both layouts.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I didn't have duplicate ID.
The error occurred when I tried to switch from dark theme to light theme.
Both of which had different parent theme. Make sure the light theme and dark theme are using the same theme style and parent theme.

Answer (score 1):

Well, in my case, I came across this question while implementing landscape and portrait modes to my app, to solve - make sure :

views should have the same id and the same type in both layouts

Answer (score 1):

Had this error on using drawer layout along with nav rails and navigation view , fixed it by removing repeating id attribute from all layouts except base layout. Also  changed the version material and appcompat versions to `com.google.android.material:material:1.6.0`, `androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1` and nav ui version as `androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.5.3`

Answer (score 0):

I received the error besides that I don't have duplicated ids.
My code was like this:

```
override fun onSaveInstanceState(): Parcelable {
    val bundle = Bundle()
    bundle.putString(SELECTED_KEY, selectedItemId)
    bundle.putParcelable(SUPER_STATE_KEY, super.onSaveInstanceState())
    return bundle
}

override fun onRestoreInstanceState(state: Parcelable) {
    if (state is Bundle) {
        selectedItemId = state.getString(SELECTED_KEY, null)
        selectedItemId?.let{
            views.forEach {view ->
                view.isSelected = it == view.tag
            }
        }
    }

    super.onRestoreInstanceState(state)
}
```

I saw that there is an open issue [here](https://github.com/HomHomLin/Android-PullToRefreshRecyclerView/issues/4). I manage to find a workaround that not crases the application when I changed the `super.onRestoreInstanceState` call parameter like this:

```
override fun onSaveInstanceState(): Parcelable {
    val bundle = Bundle()
    vgs_ring?.constraintLayoutParams()?.let {
        bundle.putParcelable(PARENT_STATE_KEY, super.onSaveInstanceState())
        bundle.putFloat(RING_POSITION_KEY, it.verticalBias)
    }
    super.onSaveInstanceState()
    return bundle
}


override fun onRestoreInstanceState(state: Parcelable) {
    var parentState : Parcelable? = null
    if (state is Bundle) {
        val curRingPosition = state.getFloat(RING_POSITION_KEY, DEFAULT_RING_POSITION)
        state.getParcelable<Parcelable?>(PARENT_STATE_KEY)?.let {
            parentState = it
        }
        vgs_ring?.constraintLayoutParams()?.let {
            it.verticalBias = curRingPosition
            calculateRingPosition()
        }
    }

    super.onRestoreInstanceState(parentState ?: super.onSaveInstanceState())
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i was using view pager with tab layout the problem was:

```
return TabLayoutMediator(binding.tabLayout, binding.viewpager, true) { tab, position ->
    tab.text = "hello $position"
    tab.id = position
}
```

replace  id with sth else like tag

Comment: We are also facing the same problem. can you please explain your answers in detail?. because of the tab layout are you facing this error?

Answer (score 0):

The error occurred when I switched from the Dark theme to the Light theme. I set a color for a button, but that color was not available in the Dark theme's colors. Therefore, it is important to ensure any colors used are available in both dark and light colors.